# How to select a perticular cell in table layout and paint with different color

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, tablelayoutpanel

I have created a Table layout in windows forms as shown in figure, i have added a right mouse button click Menu to my table, i want to color the cell when i right click on the perticuler cell, so how can i do it.

When i click `add device` the cell should paint to green color, 
When i click `delete device` it should show default color,
When i click `fire` the cell should be painted with red color
so on

The below is my form and table layout

[image: http://i48.tinypic.com/33ok3cw.jpg]

Comment: @Arun   this is what  have tried                                                                           public void addDevice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    Label l = (Label)sender;
    if (l.BackColor == SystemColors.Control)
    {
      l.BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
     }

Comment: How are you adding the label controls to the tablelayout ? Dynamically ? Context menu is linked to the tablelayoutpanel or the individual label controls ?

Comment: @Arun labels controls are added dynamically..  Context menu is linked to label controls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer for my question it can be done as shown below
First we need to find the label control(sender) which has sent the event as follows

```
    private void AssignClickEvent()
    {
        foreach (Control c in tableLayout.Controls.OfType<Label>())
        {

            c.MouseClick += tablelayout_MouseClick;
            addDevice.Click += addDevice_Click;
            deleteDevice.Click += deleteDevice_Click;
            fire.Click += fire_Click;
            fault.Click += fault_Click;
            suppress.Click += suppress_Click;

        }
    }
```

have a globle varible of pointer control

```
 public Label h = new Label();
```

then we need to copy the sender to the control

```
    private void tablelayout_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Label l = (Label)sender;

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            h = l;
            num = l.Text;
            m.MenuItems.AddRange(new MenuItem[] { addDevice, deleteDevice, fire, fault,suppress  });
            tableLayout.ContextMenu = m;
            m.Show((Control)(sender), e.Location);
        }           

    }
```

then use global control `h' to set color to the control

```
    public void addDevice_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            h.BackColor = Color.Green; ;
            comport.Write("AB");
            comport.Write(num);
            comport.Write(" "); 
            stausLable.Text = "Device "+num+" added";
            comport.WriteLine("000000000000");
        }
        catch (InvalidOperationException )
        {
            stausLable.Text = "Open communication port";

        }
    }
```

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEmW4.png]

Answer (score 1):

Hi there i dont have what you looking for but,

TableLayoutPanels don't really have 'cells' as such and are really meant to be a container for controls. This means you can't really retrieve individual rows, columns or cells. An alternative would be to use panels and put individual click events on each of these.

However if you're determined that you want to use TableLayoutPanels, you can use the XY coordinate of where the mouse click occurred on the TableLayoutPanel from EventArgs. And determine which block it is, since you've got evenly spread rows/columns.

For example if you have all the cells the same size and the the TableLayoutPanel is docked in the form this will get the selected Cell.:

```
Point selectedCell = new Point();
private void tableLayoutPanel1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
    {

       //show contextMenuStrip
        selectedCell = new Point(e.X / (tableLayoutPanel1.Width / tableLayoutPanel1.ColumnCount), e.Y / (tableLayoutPanel1.Height / tableLayoutPanel1.RowCount));
    }
}
```

Comment: can u help me in doing that..?

Comment: int row = e.X;
   int column = e.Y;

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way without having to implement those events as well as the extra variables. Assuming the contextmenu is named 'DeviceActionsContextMenu' and is linked to the label controls (as per your comment), Implement the toolstrip Item's click event -

```
    private void addDeviceToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        (contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl as Label).BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
```

Or Implement the contextmenu's Item clicked event -

```
    private void DeviceActionsContextMenu_ItemClicked(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ClickedItem == addDeviceToolStripMenuItem)
        {
            (contextMenuStrip1.SourceControl as Label).BackColor = Color.Green;
        }
    }
```